# AngularUI with Bootstrap 3.0 Support

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

When is AngularUI is going to have support for Bootstrap 3.0?I want to use Angular in association with bootstrap 3.0 as it is very specific to mobile,but presently it is only supporting bootstrap 2.3 .I have to stick up with mobile first approach as bootstrap 3.0 is having preformance benefits rather than bootstrap 2.3 .Please any one help me when it is going to be released or any other alternatives to resolve this issue.Thank you in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about predicting future... How on earth can we know when an open source library gets a new release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [branch with Bootstrap 3.X support](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/bootstrap3).
There is also another branch - [bootstrap3_bis2_modalPatch](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/bootstrap3_bis2_modalPatch), but boostrap3 branch seems to be more up-to-date.
As of today it's only a developement version, but I didn't have any problems with it.

If you are using bower, it can work with git branches too:
dependency:

```
"angular-ui-bootstrap": "git://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#bootstrap3"
```

**Update Dec 2013:**
New release of ui.bootstrap supports bootstrap 3.
(Links above are not longer working)